# Find out where a GitHub repo was forked from

Tags: git, github

[image]

In this picture, you are told where the repo was forked from. I've been looking through the github2 api and I can't seem to find a way to get this information. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the parent/source field from the show repo command.
http://develop.github.com/p/repo.html

I think that does what you want.

Comment: Parent == where forked from, source == root repo of the network.  They're not always the same thing.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that this was indeed what I was looking for and I've since gotten my script working. Thanks again!

Comment: It seems this method was removed in the newer API :(

Comment: That link is now dead